# -XX:G1ReservePercent and to-space exhausted

Tags: java, jvm, g1gc

I'm trying to understand what the `-XX:G1ReservePercent` actually does. The descriptions I found in the [official documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/g1gc-1984535.html) are not really comprehensive:

> Sets the percentage of reserve memory to keep free so as to reduce the
>   risk of to-space overflows. The default is 10 percent. When you
>   increase or decrease the percentage, make sure to adjust the total
>   Java heap by the same amount.

and the desciption of to-space exhausted log entry is this:

> When you see to-space overflow/exhausted messages in your logs, the G1
>   GC does not have enough memory for either survivor or promoted
>   objects, or for both.
>
> [...]
>
> To alleviate the problem, try the following adjustments:
>
> Increase the value of the `-XX:G1ReservePercent` option (and the total 
>   heap accordingly) to increase the amount of reserve memory for "to-space".
>
> [...]

Judging by the quote the `to-space exhausted` means that when performing mixed evacuation we do not have enough a free region to move survivors to.

But this then contradicts to the following [official tuning advice in case of Full GC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/gctuning/garbage-first-garbage-collector-tuning.htm#JSGCT-GUID-2428DA90-B93D-48E6-B336-A849ADF1C552) (emphasize mine):

> Force G1 to start marking earlier. G1 automatically determines the
>   Initiating Heap Occupancy Percent (IHOP) threshold based on earlier
>   application behavior. If the application behavior changes, these
>   predictions might be wrong. There are two options: **Lower the target
>   occupancy for when to start space-reclamation by increasing the buffer
>   used in an adaptive IHOP calculation by modifying
>   `-XX:G1ReservePercent`;**

So what is the buffer and what does setting `-XX:G1ReservePercent` do (From the first glance AdaptiveIHOP has nothing to do with it...) ?

Does it keep some heap space always reserved so when mixed evacuation occur we always have free regiong to move survivors to?

Or the space is used for G1 internal housekeeping tasks? If so it is not clear what data the to-space contains so it exhausted?

Answer (score 7):

To me, understanding what it really does, means to go the source code. I chose `jdk-15`.

The best description of this flag is [here](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1_globals.hpp#l188):

> It determines the minimum reserve we should have in the heap to minimize the probability of promotion failure.

Excellent, so this has to do with "promotion failures" (whatever those are). But according to you quote in bold, this has something to do with `AdaptiveIHOP` also? Well [yes, this parameter matters only in AdaptiveIHOP](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l840) (which is on by default).

Another thing to notice is that `G1ReservePercentage` has [no guarantee to be maintained all the time](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l271), it is a best effort.

If you look at how it is used in the very next line:

```
if (_free_regions_at_end_of_collection > _reserve_regions) {
    absolute_max_length = _free_regions_at_end_of_collection - _reserve_regions;
}
```

things start to make some sense (for that bold statement). Notice how `_reserve_regions` are **extracted** for some computation. `G1` will *reserve* that space for "promotion failures" (we will get to that).

If `G1` reserves that space, it means *less* space is available for actual allocations. So if you "increase this buffer" (you make `G1ReservePercent` bigger as the quote suggests), your space for new objects becomes *smaller* and as such the time when `GC` needs to kick in will come *sooner*, so the time for when space reclamation needs to happen will come *sooner* too ("Lower the target occupancy for when to start space-reclamation..."). It is one complicated sentence, but in simple words it means that :

> If you increase `G1ReservePercentage`, space will be needed to be reclaimed faster (more often GC calls).

Which, to be fair, is obvious. Not that I agree that you *should* increase that value, but this is what that sentence says.

---

After a certain GC cycle, be that `minor`, `mixed` or `major`, `G1` [knows how many regions are free](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1Policy.cpp#l785):

```
_free_regions_at_end_of_collection = _g1h->num_free_regions();
```

Which of course, is the length of ["free list"](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/heapRegionManager.hpp#l231):

```
return _free_list.length();
```

Based on this value and `_reserve_regions` (`G1ReservePercent`) plus the target pause time (`200 ms` by default) it can compute how many regions it needs for the next cycle. By the time next cycle ends, there might be a case when there are no empty regions (or the ones that are empty can not take all the live Objects that are supposed to be moved). Where is `Eden` supposed to move *live* Objects (`Survivor`), or, if `old region` is fragmented  - where are *live* objects supposed to be moved to defragmente? This is what this buffer is for.

It acts as a [safety-net](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1IHOPControl.cpp#l102) (the comments in the code make this far more easier to understand). This is needed in the hopes that it will avoid a `Full GC`. Because if there are no free regions (or enough) to move live Objects a Full GC needs to happen (most probably followed by a `young GC` also).

---

This value is usually known to be small when [this message is present in logs](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk15/file/0dabbdfd97e6/src/hotspot/share/gc/g1/g1CollectedHeap.cpp#l3140). Either increase it, or *much* better give more heap to the application.