# Big byte arrays use more heap than expected

Tags: java, arrays, memory, out-of-memory

Using a 1 GB Java heap (`-Xmx1g`), I store data in many large byte arrays. I get an `OutOfMemoryError` quite some time **before** 1 GB of data is stored. At that time, there is still quite a lot of free heap as calculated by Runtime `rt.maxMemory() - rt.totalMemory() + rt.freeMemory()`:

| byte array size | approx. data that can be stored | approx. free heap shown |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2^18 (262144) | 800 MB | 270 MB |
| 2^17 (131072) | 930 MB | 140 MB |
| 2^16 (65536) | 997 MB | 72 MB |
| 2^15 (32768) | 1032 MB | 36 MB |

Why is heap size calculation off for large byte arrays and can I do something to mend it?

---

Note: When using 2^19 (or larger) sized byte arrays, a different thing occurs: [Java byte array of 1 MB or more takes up twice the RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506337/java-byte-array-of-1-mb-or-more-takes-up-twice-the-ram) - let's focus this question on 2^18 sized byte arrays.

Run with 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.11, both on Windows `java -cp .\lib\* -Xmx1g tryit.Main` and Debian `java -cp .:./lib/* -Xmx1g tryit.Main`:

```
package tryit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        byte[][] array = new byte[1000000][];
        long freeAtStart = free();
        System.out.println("Free at start: " + freeAtStart);
        int chunkSize = 2<<17; // This is 2^18.
        System.out.println("Chunk size   : " + chunkSize);
        for (int n = 0; n < 1000000; n++) {
            if (n % 50 == 0) {
                long currentFree = free();
                System.out.printf("%d: stored %d / allocated %d / free %d\n", n, n * chunkSize, freeAtStart - currentFree, currentFree);
            }
            array[n] = new byte[chunkSize];
        }
    }
    static long free() throws Exception {
        System.gc(); // Called just in case - there should not be anything to garbage collect.
        Thread.sleep(100); // Give GC some time to work
        return Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() + Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
    }
}
```

And finally the (shortened) output of four runs:

```
2^15:
Free at start: 1068751960 / Chunk size: 32768
31500: stored 1032192000 / allocated 1032933912 / free 35818048

2^16:
Free at start: 1068751960 / Chunk size: 65536
15200: stored 996147200 / allocated 996627400 / free 72124560

2^17:
Free at start: 1068751960 / Chunk size: 131072
7100: stored 930611200 / allocated 930960032 / free 137791928

2^18:
Free at start: 1068751960 / Chunk size: 262144
3050: stored 799539200 / allocated 799823160 / free 268928800

2^19 (humongous objects - allocation size is two times stored size):
Free at start: 1068751960 / Chunk size: 524288
1000: stored 524288000 / allocated 1048811120 / free 19940840
```

Comment: Your test is not correct. `System.gc();` will **not** start GC with 100%. This is **only recommendation** to JVM to do so. JVM can **not do GC** instead.

Comment: I call `System.gc()` "just in case". There is nothing to garbage collect (everything is strongly referenced), so the example does not need to try trigger gc.

Comment: This is my output for 2^18 on Java 17: `3050: stored 799539200 / allocated 1064828992 / free 1617856` *edit* that was with the `gc()` call removed, with it I  get `267966664`, i.e. very similar to you. So the gc call does make a difference?

Comment: that `1GB` is not used only by you - VM has it's data too, and it's not even entirely given to you, garbage collectors need they own structures to work, like SATB queues, or even [things like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64236979/1059372). what you see is pretty normal, to me.

Comment: @oleg.cherednik under the current implementations, I checked a few, it will (assuming default flags). The thing is that `System.gc` starts a concurrent mark phase - what that triggers (or not) in turn, depends on the current heap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As described in the linked answer ([Java byte array of 1 MB or more takes up twice the RAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58506337/java-byte-array-of-1-mb-or-more-takes-up-twice-the-ram)) and the [G1 garbage collector documentation](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/g1gc.html) the G1 garbage collector divides the heap into regions of 1 MByte (2^20 bytes) each. For a 1GB heap that gives 1024 regions (probably a bit less due to administrative overhead).

Naively you would expect the a region of 2^20 bytes can hold 4 byte arrays of 2^18 bytes each - but unfortunately this is not the case. Byte arrays are objects, and objects have a hidden object header (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/50509263 for an explanation).

So the effective size of a `byte[262144]` is not 262144 bytes, it is 262160 bytes (depending on the JVM and the maximum heap size it could be even more), which means that each region can only hold 3 byte arrays of length 262144.

Combining 3 byte arrays per region with 1024 regions would give you a maximum of 3072 byte arrays of 262144 bytes for a 1 GB heap, which matches nicely with your numbers.

---

What you can do about it:

- use larger regions (by supplying `-XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4M`) - a 4MB region can hold 15 byte arrays of length 262144, whereas 4 regions of 1MB can hold only 12 byte arrays of length 262144
- use slightly smaller byte arrays - a 1MB region can hold only 3 byte arrays of length 262144, but 4 byte arrays of length 262128

---

Note: this post uses 2^20 to mean *two to the power of twenty*, which is not the same as the java expression `2^20`, but rather `1<<20`